# Caffe: GPU CUDA error after training: Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (30 vs. 0) unknown error

Tags: cuda, nvidia, caffe

Sometimes after the training or when I stop the training manually by pressing **CTRL + C** I get this cuda error:

Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (30 vs. 0)  unknown error

This only started to happen recently, though. Does anyone have experienced that before or do you know how to fix this or what the problem is?

Complete log:

```
I1027 09:29:37.779079 11959 caffe.cpp:217] Using GPUs 0
I1027 09:29:37.780676 11959 caffe.cpp:222] GPU 0: �|���
F1027 09:29:37.780697 11959 common.cpp:151] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (30 vs. 0)  unknown error
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f6cc4f465cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7f6cc4f48433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7f6cc4f4615b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7f6cc4f48e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7f6cc5558032  caffe::Caffe::SetDevice()
    @           0x40b3f8  train()
    @           0x407590  main
    @     0x7f6cc3eb7830  __libc_start_main
    @           0x407db9  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
```

Comment: this problem occurs due to the program `caffe` still runs or holds resource. in that case it might be killed, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nvidia-smi` command to see which programs are running on `GPU` & `CPU`. If you see any unwanted instance of `caffe` is running still after pressing `ctrl+c` is pressed you should kill those with process id. Like below:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 352.63     Driver Version: 352.63         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 980 Ti  Off  | 0000:01:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 58%   83C    P2   188W / 260W |   1164MiB /  6142MiB |     96%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 980 Ti  Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 53%   73C    P2   127W / 260W |    585MiB /  6143MiB |     35%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1101    C   ...-xx/build/tools/caffe   788MiB |
|    0      1570    G   /usr/bin/X                                     235MiB |
|    0      1594    C   /usr/bin/python                                102MiB |
|    0      2387    G   compiz                                          10MiB |
|    0      3984    G   /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB      2MiB |
|    1     25056    C   /usr/bin/caffe                                 563MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

you should kill with this command `sudo kill -9 1101`

Comment: The thing is there is nothing which is caffe. I have already tried that! There is only sth like: **/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg** and **compiz**

Comment: Try it by (a) installing CUDA 8.0 and (b) change the caffe makefile.config.example and change the "50"s to "61"
-gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
-gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50

Comment: I already have CUDA 8.0. But I will check the second option! I will let you know!

Comment: I did not try yet, sorry! I was really busy! I will tell you as soon as I know! But it is hard to find out as the error only occurs ocassionally.

Comment: Tbh I think the compute_50 or 60 or whaever depends on the GPU u are using

Answer (score 0):

try to do `make all` --> `make test` --> `make runtest`. it should work

Comment: this issue occurs due to memory resource not being freed. Building caffe would not fix this

Answer (score 0):

After running Make all, noticed some errors regarding libcudnn libs, I had them duplicathed in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and /usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64. After leaving only the ones in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu and restarting the laptop everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

CUDA runtime error (30) might show if your program is unable to create or open the /dev/nvidia-uvm device file. This is usually fixed by installing package nvidia-modprobe:

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe`

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall/build the nvidia driver for current kernel

sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-375

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe
```

CUDA runtime error (30) might show if your program is unable to create or open the `/dev/nvidia-uvm` device file. This is usually fixed by installing package nvidia-modprobe:

([Source](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4543))